# How to send SMS message via windows form

Tags: c#, sms

I have created an App that needs to send confirmation to a user via a mobile phone number. I have no idea where to start. Does anyone know where I can find anywhere to help me with this problem ? I have looked around and most of them have comments that people say they don't work. For example [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3bff37/sending-sms-via-windows-form-application/) and [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b8d90a/send-sms-using-C-Sharp-net/)

Comment: use the Twilio service https://www.twilio.com/

Answer (score 2):

You may use AT commands. Here are some general steps:

**Step 1:** Connect the device (mobile or GSM modem) to the computer and be sure to install the required drivers.

**Step 2:** Find the port number which the device is connected using the device manager and configure the `SerialPort`, e.g:

```
System.IO.Ports.SerialPort serialPort1= new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort();
serialPort1.PortName = "COM7"; 
serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
serialPort1.ReadBufferSize = 10000;
serialPort1.ReadTimeout = 1000;
serialPort1.WriteBufferSize = 10000;
serialPort1.WriteTimeout = 10000;

serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;
```

**Step 3:** Choose the sending format

```
serialPort1.Write("AT+CMGF=1" + (char)13); 
//The values 0 and 1 refer to SMS PDU mode and SMS text mode respectively
```

**Step 4:** Define the Service Center Address

```
serialPort1.Write("AT+CSCA=\"" + SMSCADDRESS + "\"" + (char)13);
//e.g. SMSCADDRESS = +9891100500
```

**Step 5:** Send your message

```
serialPort1.Write("AT+CMGS=\"" + "09123976634" + "\"" + (char)13 );
serialPort1.Write("Hello Message" + (char)26);
```

I was searching for this some years ago and found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/GSM_Modem_AT_COMMAND.aspx) as a working example. Also [this](http://www.developershome.com/sms/) links has good information.

Comment: Great, looks perfect. I know it's a totally new question but do you know how I could send the message and for it to automatically pop up with a name rather than a number ? Like one you can't reply to.

Comment: @thisOneGuy to be honest I haven't try that case.

Comment: no worries, appreciate the help :))